# Excel IF and VLOOKUP function help

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vlookup

[image]

The exercise is to use `IF()` and `VLOOKUP()` functions to return the tax rate based on the annual income and number of people in the household.

So far I've tried inputting:

```
=IF(AND(B$2=3,C$2<=35000),VLOOKUP(C2,'Tax Index'!A3:E8,5))
```

but the third attribute in `VLOOKUP()`, or the `col_index_num` needs to be changed in order to return the correct tax rate, but that is manual work and isn't the point of the exercise.

Can anyone help me go through this problem?

Comment: Is there a good reason you can't combine the reference tables into one, since one is for income up to 35,000 and one from 35,000 upwards, then split again at 100,000. This would avoid the IF altogether, just let VLOOKUP do it's thing. Other than that, Lance is on the money with a calculation for the column_index.

Answer (score 4):

The third parameter of the VLOOKUP() function is the column *of the table you want to address*.  So since for 1,2,3 you want columns 3,4,5 then you just need to add 2 to the Type of Household parameter, like so:

```
=IF(AND(B$2=3,C$2<=35000),VLOOKUP(C2,'Tax Index'!A3:E8,B2+2))
```

so for your first line, the Type of Household of 3 would give you column 5 of the table.